# Tethering options for the laptop and the phone

Tags: tethering, wifi-tethering, usb-tethering, bluetooth-tethering

I have a rooted Samsung Galaxy S3.

I am about to go abroad and will need to connect my laptop
to the Internet without having someone come and install a
DSL or cable router (as the waiting time to install these is
quite long I would be gone before the internet technicians drop by).

So what I have decided is to purchase a SIM card and connect my laptop
to my android phone to do internet browsing. My understanding is that with tethering I can transform this phone into a router or wireless hotspot.

1. What are tethering options (settings or apps) for this phone?
2. Is it better to connect the PC to the phone wirelessly, via a USB
   cable to use tethering, or via Bluetooth tethering? *In terms of speed, I guess Wi-Fi tethering would be superior here.*

Comment: Have you checked the [most frequented questions tagged 'tethering'](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tethering?sort=frequent)? Lots of solutions there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, bluetooth tethering (using [Bluetooth Garden](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opengarden.android.MeshClient)) has been problematic. It disconnects too often, or can't open certain sites.

USB tethering (via [ClockworkMod Tether](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.tether)) was OK. This way, my phone would be charging while providing internet to my laptop. Downside is I needed to install a program (not an issue, because the program is safe) on my laptop. Another downside is I couldn't tether another device (like a tablet) to the phone.

Turning my phone into a hotspot, was a better choice. I could surf with little issues. I could connect my tablet or laptop to the phone via WiFi. However, this drained my battery quickly. I'd occasionally fix this by plugging my phone to an outlet with a charger.

Answer (score 1):

I use all 3 methods and prefer USB tethering if possible.

Some notes on each:

**USB tethering**

- Exclusive for one device (there's only 1 cable)
- charges the phone
- Safe (network is not exposed wirelessly)
- No driver needed (recent Macs/Win/Linux)
- Best speed and latency (USB 2.0 has 480MBit/s)
- Tethers any active connection on the phone (wifi, 3G)

**Wifi tethering**

- more than one client at once possible
- Wifi chip may draw extra power in this mode
- Easy and well known setup on clients
- No strings attached :-)

**Bluetooth tethering**

- Doesn't draw extra power when enabled
- Can be enabled 24/7
- Capps speed at respective BT speed (2MBit?)
- It's really OK (speedwise) for surfing

I tether my PC via USB (most of the time to a wifi network], my tablet tethers via BT primarily, but I switch to wifi as needed too. I use [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.refluxa.android.bat) to automatically enable BT tethering on my Nexus phone. The "BT tethering always on" is very cool when I'm on a train and use my tablet: No need to enable (and remembering to afterwards disable) wifi tethering, the phone just stays in my pocket.