# Auto-reconnect Bluetooth (BT) or USB tethering

Tags: usb, tethering, wifi-tethering, bluetooth-tethering

When on vacation I use my smartphone (Android 7.1.1 Nougat) as a modem for my laptop (Windows 10 Home) and tablet (Android 6.0 Marshmallow), tethering to the laptop with USB and the tablet with Bluetooth. This works fine and the speed is acceptable, but every time I disconnect/go out of BT range I have to re-establish the connection. With WiFi tethering this problem does not occur, but WiFi uses a lot more battery power.

Is there any way to make USB and/or BT re-connection automatic?

@Ce4's answer to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/48240/tethering-options-for-the-laptop-and-the-phone) (jun 2013) mentions an app for permanent BT tethering but the link is broken.

Comment: Under what conditions do you want to re-enable usb tethering? an automation tool like tasker could do the job?

Answer (score 1):

There are several apps available which can do this (even without root), for example [Hot Spot Starter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.thjunge11.autohotspotfree&hl=en) or [Hotspot Automatik](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.christian_heinisch.hotspot.enablehotspot).

Answer (score 0):

[This topic](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127930/automatically-tether-usb) shows an answer using [Automate app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate). Note that, according to that topic, it requires root access.

[image: Flowchart]